# How to get correct caret absolute position

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

I am using `range.getBoundingClientRect` to get caret position but it gives wrong values when the `end` key is pressed.

Currently, I have a content-editable div and a caret div:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sodales tellus nulla, quis viverra ipsum accumsan nec. Vivamus felis velit, dictum nec purus sed, placerat placerat libero. 
</div>
<div id="caret"></div>
```

I detect when selection change to update caret position:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
  const rect = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
  document.getElementById('caret').style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
  document.getElementById('caret').style.top = `${rect.top}px`;
})
```

When I press the end key, my caret goes at the beginning of the next line instead of going at the end of the current one. This is because `getBoundingClientRect` gives bad values.

Here is a reproduction:

https://jsfiddle.net/2dauymov/10/

I am on Chrome 78.